# Extracting special character in string to new column

Tags: r, dplyr, extract, special-characters, tidyr

I read a lot of the other answers, but didn't seem to find what I needed.  I am trying to create a database of NFL team record data, but I am having trouble correctly creating a new variable of "Seed" and keeping the data.  So I have NFL team names with special characters on the end of some of them, denoting winning their division or wild card playoff spots, that I want to keep. For example here is my df:

```
Tm
New England Patriots*
Buffalo Bills+
New York Jets
Miami Dolphins
```

I know this works, but doesn't seem like the correct way to do it

```
#create new variable of "Seed"
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(Seed = Tm)

#remove all but special characters from "Seed"
df$Seed=gsub("[A-z0-9. ]", "", df$Seed)

#remove special characters from "Tm"
df$Tm=gsub("[\\*\\+]", "", df$Tm)
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is just separate them into 2 columns without creating additional data to clean, like this:

```
Tm                       Seed
New England Patriots     *
Buffalo Bills            +
New York Jets
Miami Dolphins
```

In pseudo code: Create new variable "Seed" -> Extract and remove from "Tm" special characters "*" & "+" and transfer to new variable "Seed" -> if "Tm" does not contain "*" or "+" then leave corresponding column in "Seed" blank

What is the correct way of doing this?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `strcapture("(.+?)(\\W*$)",df$Tm,data.frame(Tm = character(),speed = character()))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution using stringr.

```
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")

df <- tibble(Tm = c("New England Patriots*", "Buffalo Bills+", "New York Jets"))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Seed = str_extract(Tm, "[\\+\\*]$"),
    Tm = str_replace(Tm, "[\\+\\*]$", "")
  )

> df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Tm                   Seed
  <chr>                <chr>
1 New England Patriots *
2 Buffalo Bills        +
3 New York Jets        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with tidyr's `extract` function.

```r
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Tm = c("New England Patriots*", "Buffalo Bills+",
                        "New York Jets", "Miami Dolphins"))

df %>%
  extract(col = Tm, regex = "^([^\\*\\+]+)([\\+\\*]?)$",
          into = c("Tm", "Seed"))
#>                     Tm Seed
#> 1 New England Patriots    *
#> 2        Buffalo Bills    +
#> 3        New York Jets     
#> 4       Miami Dolphins
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, thank you very much! This requires one less step, if you want blanks instead of NA for rows that don't have special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R approach :

```
#Extract + or * at the end of the string 
temp <- regmatches(df$Tm, gregexpr('[+*]$', df$Tm))
#Replace 0 length characters with NA
temp[lengths(temp) == 0] <- NA
#Assign as new column
df$Seed <- unlist(temp)
#Remove from original column
df$Tm <- sub('[+*]$', '', df$Tm) 
df
#                    Tm Seed
#1 New England Patriots    *
#2        Buffalo Bills    +
#3        New York Jets <NA>
#4       Miami Dolphins <NA>
```